# Getting null value in the Grand Total column in the Pivot Table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the query which returning me the number of categories in one cloumn and other column are dynamic  column they are giving me the the months between start date & end date and this column are returning me the amount of the categories sold on that month.

I want to add the **Grand Total**  at the end of the row in the query

Here's My Query

[image]

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @subtotal AS FLOAT,
            @startdate as datetime,
            @enddate as datetime
            DECLARE @ColumnsRollup AS VARCHAR (MAX)

            set @startdate = '1-Mar-2014'
            set @enddate =   '1-Aug-2014'

;with cte (StartDate, EndDate) as
(
    select min(@startdate) StartDate, max(@enddate) EndDate    
    union all
    select dateadd(mm, 1, StartDate), EndDate
    from cte
    where StartDate < EndDate
) 
select  StartDate
into #tempDates
from cte 


select @cols =  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), StartDate, 120)) 
                    from #tempDates
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') +  ',[Total]' 






SET  @query =           'select  ledger_name,
                        ' + @cols + '                        
                        from
                        (
                        SELECT 


                       CASE WHEN (GROUPING(ledger_name) = 1) THEN ''Grand Total''
                       ELSE ledger_name END AS ledger_name,


                       ISNULL(SUM(amount),0) Amount, 

                       CASE WHEN (GROUPING(StartDate) = 1) THEN ''Total''
                       ELSE convert(CHAR(10), StartDate, 120) END StartDate

                       FROM #tempDates d
                       left join Rs_Ledger_Master AS LM on  d.StartDate between '''+convert(varchar(10), @startdate, 120)+''' and '''+convert(varchar(10), @enddate, 120)+'''                      
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Payment_Master AS PM ON PM.ledger_code = LM.ledger_code and  month(paid_date) = month(StartDate) and  year(paid_date) = year(StartDate) 
                       group by 
                       ledger_name,StartDate WITH ROLLUP              
                       ) d
                        pivot
                        (
                          SUM(Amount)
                          for StartDate in (' + @cols + ')
                        ) p                                                                 
                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN ledger_name = ''Grand Total'' THEN 1 END'
        execute sp_executesql @query;
        drop table #tempDates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can do is, try to use the ROLLUP option in your inner query, which actually returns addtional row for the SUM(Amount), which you can call as Total and add this column to your column list.

Here is the change what I think you need to do

Add total column at the end of your column list

```
SET @cols= @cols + ',[Total]'
```

Add the rollup option to your inner query. Note that, the case statement is required to change the text as total for the row.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @subtotal AS FLOAT,
            @startdate as datetime,
            @enddate as datetime
            DECLARE @ColumnsRollup AS VARCHAR (MAX)

            set @startdate = '1-Mar-2014'
            set @enddate =   '1-Aug-2014'

;with cte (StartDate, EndDate) as
(
    select min(@startdate) StartDate, max(@enddate) EndDate    
    union all
    select dateadd(mm, 1, StartDate), EndDate
    from cte
    where StartDate < EndDate
) 
select  StartDate
into #tempDates
from cte 


select @cols =  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), StartDate, 120)) 
                    from #tempDates
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') +  ',[Total]' 


SET  @query =           'select  ledger_name,
                        ' + @cols + '                        
                        from
                        (
                        SELECT 


                       ledger_name,


                       ISNULL(SUM(amount),0) Amount, 

                       CASE WHEN (GROUPING(StartDate) = 1) THEN ''Total''
                       ELSE convert(CHAR(10), StartDate, 120) END StartDate

                       FROM #tempDates d
                       left join Rs_Ledger_Master AS LM on  d.StartDate between '''+convert(varchar(10), @startdate, 120)+''' and '''+convert(varchar(10), @enddate, 120)+'''                      
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Payment_Master AS PM ON PM.ledger_code = LM.ledger_code and  month(paid_date) = month(StartDate) and  year(paid_date) = year(StartDate) 
                       group by 
                       ledger_name,StartDate WITH ROLLUP              
                       ) d
                        pivot
                        (
                          SUM(Amount)
                          for StartDate in (' + @cols + ')
                        ) p      
                        WHERE ledger_name IS NOT NULL
                         UNION ALL
                        select  ledger_name,
                        ' + @cols + ' FROM
                       (SELECT ''Grand Total'' AS ledger_name,
                       ISNULL(SUM(amount),0) Amount, 
                       CASE WHEN (GROUPING(StartDate) = 1) THEN ''Total''
                       ELSE convert(CHAR(10), StartDate, 120) END StartDate

                       FROM #tempDates d
                       left join Rs_Ledger_Master AS LM on  d.StartDate between '''+convert(varchar(10), @startdate, 120)+''' and '''+convert(varchar(10), @enddate, 120)+'''                      
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Payment_Master AS PM ON PM.ledger_code = LM.ledger_code and  month(paid_date) = month(StartDate) and  year(paid_date) = year(StartDate) 
                       group by StartDate WITH ROLLUP              
                       ) d
                       pivot
                       (
                         SUM(Amount)
                         for StartDate in (' + @cols + ')
                       ) p


                        '
        print @query
        execute sp_executesql @query;
        drop table #tempDates
```

You need additional union all to get the last summary row

You can refer the following article for using ROLLUP
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: it is saying invalid cloumn name total

Comment: ok, sorry, we need to add the total to the startdate column, not the ledger_name column. changed the query, can you check?

Comment: still not got I am gettiing null values at the zero'th column and also not getiing sum of the column

Comment: I got the the sub total but did not got the grand total below can you pleas tell me that part also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57084/discussion-between-hardik-and-kiran-hegde).